# article usage: "the faces of the human"

Tags: articles, generic-noun-phrases

> 1. A dusty wind whips in the sweaty faces of the humans.
> 2. A dusty wind whips in the sweaty faces of humans.

The first sentence uses two ***the**s*. Is the article *the* required in front of *humans*? Which is correct, 1. or 2.?

Comment: "wind whips in the faces" is non-standard (misuse of preposition).  Native speakers will see it as incorrect or clumsy.

Comment: @jwpat7 So you mean it should be "on" instead of "in"? A dusty wind whips on the sweaty faces of the humans.

Comment: No, *on* would be even worse.  Leave out the preposition entirely. Eg, "The wind whips their faces".

Comment: @jwpat7 Is it correct if I say "their sweaty faces"? A dusty wind whips their sweaty faces.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, although a bit busy.

Comment: Can't really agree with any of this. "Wind whipping in (anyone's) face" is a standard and common idiom in English. "Whipping (anyone's) face" is quite another thing entirely. You can say it, but it's not common, and it would imply that the wind is extremely severe and lashing, almost _cutting_ in its intensity.

Comment: "whipping in" is what the whipper-in does. "whipping into" is what the wind does.

Answer (score 6):

Without the article, the sentence would mean that a dusty wind *always* whips in the faces of humans; in other words, it would state that part of the condition of being human is that a dusty wind always whips in one's face. (We know that this is not the case, of course.)

With the article, the sentence means that *at this particular time and pertaining to this particular group of humans*, a dusty wind is whipping in their faces.

Comment: it should be "on" instead of "in"? A dusty wind whips on the sweaty faces of the humans.

Comment: Quite simply, no. "On" is just not how it's said. "In" is the way we say it.

Comment: Maybe it's the other way around: "part of the condition of being a dusty wind is that it whips human's sweaty faces"?